# Regression coefficient negative for a binary predictor

Tags: r

**Explanation**: I contrast-coded the binary predictor as the following

```
vid_df$segment <- forcats::fct_relevel (vid_df$segment, 'Long', 'Short')
contrasts(vid_df$segment) = cbind(c(-.5,.5)) 
contrasts(vid_df$segment) # Long  -0.5, Short  0.5
```

I ran the following glmer model:

```
m1 <- glmer (correct ~ segment * subtitles * LexTALE_score_log + span_z +
              (1|item) + (1|participant_private_id),
             glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)),
             data = vid_df, family = binomial)
```

I got this output:

```
Fixed effects:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                           -0.35536    0.87681  -0.405  0.68527   
segment1                              -4.59902    1.67671  -2.743  0.00609 **
subtitles1                             3.07357    1.66044   1.851  0.06416 . 
LexTALE_score_log                      0.82987    0.46737   1.776  0.07580 . 
span_z                                 0.02952    0.08801   0.335  0.73728   
segment1:subtitles1                   -1.49222    3.32560  -0.449  0.65364   
segment1:LexTALE_score_log             2.65948    0.93924   2.832  0.00463 **
subtitles1:LexTALE_score_log          -1.59378    0.93008  -1.714  0.08660 . 
segment1:subtitles1:LexTALE_score_log  0.85002    1.86369   0.456  0.64832    **
```

The negative estimate for "segment" suggests a *decrease* in the log odds of correct responses in "short segment" compared to "long segment".

**Problem**: HOWEVER, both the descriptive data and the predicted data from the glmer model suggest that participants actually *produced more* "correct responses" in the "short segment" than the "long segment".

```
  #            Long Short
  # Incorrect  177   169
  # Correct    423   441

plot_model(m1, type = "pred", term = "segment") # higher predicted probabilities for "correct" in the short segment
```

**Question**: How can the raw/predicted results (more accuracy in the short condition) be reconciled with the regression coefficient (lower accuracy in the short condition)?

*What I did*: I calculated the accuracy for the two segment conditions to confirm my observation. The short condition had slightly higher accuracy (72.29%) than the long condition (70.5%).

**Update**: As a comment suggested, a model with interaction terms requires a different interpretation for the individual coefficients. For example the term "segment1" shows the estimate for "short segment" across both subtitle conditions (sum-coded; -.5 no-sub, .5 sub) and when "LexTALE/vocabulary" scores are 0.

I think the negative term "segment1" can be interpreted as that participants in the "short segment" condition with lower vocabulary scores produced more incorrect responses across subtitle conditions compared to their counterparts in the "long segment". The below figure may illustrate this effect:

[image]

Do you agree with this interpretation?

Your comments and suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show the results from the full model.  There are interaction terms that will affect the interpretation.

Comment: @Dave2e I added the results from the full model.

Comment: Interpretation is correct for the low scores, you will need to mention what happens for the high score for completeness